# Prevent class .cke_show_borders to be added to table element in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor4.x

When I load the table element in CKeditor 4.11.4 Eg.`<table><td>Hello</td></table>` then it adds className cke_show_borders by default like `<table class="cke_show_borders"><td>Hello</td></table>`.
The config contains allowedContents as true.
Also, I think that cke_show_borders class has been added so that the table element always has a border which is not required in my case. So how can I prevent cke_show_borders class from getting added?

when I do allowedContent as false it removes all the HTML element which was not desired.

Answer (score 1):

This issue due to the Ck-editor plugin 'showborders'.
To remove this border remove plugin from Ck-editor config.

```
config.removePlugins = 'showborders';
```

Comment: thanks it worked but unclear as to why you removed cloudservices??

Comment: No need to remove "elementspath, cloudservices," , only  remove 'showborders'. accidentally copied from my code.